# How to remove the separator line of navigation bar in swiftui?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview

[image]

Not able to remove the separator line. Tried setting background image and adding attributes, setting background colour but none of these are working.

After setting isTranslucent true, for colours other than white separator is not visible but in case of white it is visible.

```
init() {
        UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
    }
```

and I am using  .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)

Comment: Without seeing the code you're using, it's hard to help. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @ScottMatthewman I have added the code.

Comment: What you have added isn't a [mre]